# How can I override views in Solidus?

Tags: solidus

How do you override a view in Solidus?

Currently I am copying the view from Solidus Gem and into my application - which I find error prone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solidus 2.2.0 introduced a frontend views override generator which copies a view into your own host application.

> In order to customize a view you should copy the file into your host
>   app. Using Deface is not recommended as it provides lots of headaches
>   while debugging and degrades your shops performance.
>
> Solidus provides a generator to help with copying the right view into
>   your host app.
>
> Simply call the generator to copy all views into your host app.
>
> ```
> $ bundle exec rails g solidus:views:override
> ```
>
> If you only want to copy certain views into your host app, you can
>   provide the --only argument:
>
> ```
> $ bundle exec rails g solidus:views:override --only products/show
> ```
>
> The argument to --only can also be a substring of the name of the view 
>   from the app/views/spree folder:
>
> ```
> $ bundle exec rails g solidus:views:override --only product
> ```

[Readme Master link](https://github.com/solidusio/solidus/tree/master/frontend#override-views) - 
[Readme 2.2.0 Link - if master changes](https://github.com/solidusio/solidus/tree/v2.2/frontend#override-views)